# (windows) Set more cpus shortcut affinity for a .exe program

Tags: windows, cmd, shortcut

I would like to set 3 specific cpus/threads on a shortcut for a .exe image.

I've tried adding in the shortcut destination the line

```
%ComSpec% /C start /Normal /affinity C000 path.
```

In hex it should select the last 2 cpus for an 8 core.
But it doesn't work.

The microsoft support says it is a feature limitation.

So is there a way to do that? Also via batch files or powershell scripting?

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you on a NUMA architecture system?

Comment: Don't you have a bit too much hex digits for an 8-core system? `C0` should cover it.

Comment: @lit no i'm in 64bit

Comment: @n0rd no i'm in 8 core 16t, so in the affinity they are 16 virtual cores.

Comment: But my question is, could i set it with a script instead of a target shortcut?